# How to use where clause in Pods

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I am using Pods plugin for the first time, i have created 2 pods: Movies and Producers, i have a relationship field in the movies pod for the producers and i want to display all movies produced by a certain producer, i tried this shortcode:
`[pods name="movie" where="producer.meta-value = 'clark spencer' template="Movie template"]` on the template i used this:

```
<h1>{@movietitle}</h1> <br/>
<h3>{@producer}</h3>
<img src="{@movieposter}">
```

but it's not working it displays all movies rather than filtering by producer's name. Any idea how to filter movies using where clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging i've found the correct shortcode i'm not sure what went wrong maybe it's because of the double quotes or the spaces but this shortcode worked for me: 
 `[pods name="movie" where= ' producer.post_title= "clark spencer" ' template="Mov"]`

Answer (score 0):

if get this right producer is you relationship field in the movie CPT/Pod? And is this a Bi-directional relation? And the Name of the Producer is the post_title? Producer itself links to the "full entry" of a producer so you are missing in which field (e.g producer.post_title ) that where should search

anyway it's easier to use

`[pods name="producer" where="post_title.meta-value = 'clark spencer' template="Movie template"]`

And as Template:

```
<div>
   <h3>{@post_title}</h3>  //which field from Producer do you Want to show?  

    [if movies]
        [each movies] //loops through all related movies from the producer
          <h1>{@movietitle}</h1>
          <img src="{@movieposter}">
        [/each]
     [/if
</div>
```

That being said i'm not sure it's a good idea to hardcode a search, although depending on your use case maybe read - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem
and rephrase your question.

The Video has an example of displaying related stuff! 
More Information&Video: http://pods.io/docs/build/template-tags-in-pods-templates/

Comment: The name of the producer is the post_title, i tried that but it's still not working